# AG Grid React: Best way to implement search/filtering with SSRM with an external search input?

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I have

```
const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = useState("");
```

with

```
const onGridReady = (api) => {
  gridAPI = api;
  api.setServerSideDatasource({
    getRows: (rowParams) => getGroupsData({ rowParams: rowParams }),
  });
};
```

and right now to update the data when searchParam changes:

```
const debouncedSearchTerm = useDebounce(searchTerm);

useEffect(() => {
  if (gridAPI) {
    gridAPI.setServerSideDatasource({
      getRows: (rowParams) =>
        getGroupsData({
          rowParams: rowParams,
          searchTerm: debouncedSearchTerm,
        }),
    });
  }
}, [debouncedSearchTerm]);
```

This works. But while running cypress tests (inside `HeadlessChrome`) visiting the page throws this error:

```
Cannot read properties of null (reading 'getServerSideInitialRowCount')
```

I can see from the stack trace that `gridAPI?.setServerSideDatasource()` inside the `useEffect` is the culprit.

I also feel that setting a new datasource every time search input changes may not be the best way. How to update the param?